# Combinación de tecla no funciona si el focus esta en un control CEFSHARP

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo un Método que gestiona los comandos/atajos de teclado inicialmente despachados con la tecla `Control`; esta asociado a la acción `keydown` del formulario:

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
            {
                switch (e.KeyCode)
                {
                    case Keys.F12:
                        //Comando 1
                        break;
                    case Keys.N:
                        //Comando 2 nueva ventana
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

el problema es que estoy Implementando un `BrowserControl` de la librería `CEFSHARP` y si este control tiene el `focus` activo, no me detecta los comandos/atajos de teclado.

```
public void InitializeChromium(string Url)
        {
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            Cefinit = Cef.Initialize(settings);
            BrowserControl = new ChromiumWebBrowser(Url)
            {
                Name = "WebBrowser",
                MenuHandler = new SearchContextMenuHandler(this),
                DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler(download_img)
            };
            Controls.Add(BrowserControl);
        }
```

he identificado dentro de `CEFSHARP` y su documentación que existe algo:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/79/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/KeyboardHandler.cs

**Pero no logro pasar el evento del control con el focus al Form, o ejecutar mi código dentro de la interface `IKeyboardHandler`, Alguna idea de como resolverlo?**

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es implementar la interface [IKeyboardHandler](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/86.0.x/html/T_CefSharp_IKeyboardHandler.htm)

```
public class MyKeyboardHandler : IKeyboardHandler
{
   private Form _form;

   public MyKeyboardHandler(Form form)
   {
      _form = form;
   }


   public void OnKeyEvent(
    IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser,
    IBrowser browser,
    KeyType type,
    int windowsKeyCode,
    int nativeKeyCode,
    CefEventFlags modifiers,
    bool isSystemKey)
   {

      // Tú código
      // _form.Form1_KeyDown(null, new KeyEventArgs(Keys.F12 | Keys.Shift));
      ...
   }

   public void OnKeyEvent(
    IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser,
    IBrowser browser,
    KeyType type,
    int windowsKeyCode,
    int nativeKeyCode,
    CefEventFlags modifiers,
    bool isSystemKey,
    ref bool isKeyboardShortcut)
   {
      // Tú código
      ...
   }
}
```

Después, asignarle una instancia al objecto Chromium pasando el form como referencia.

```
BrowserControl = new ChromiumWebBrowser(Url)
{
   Name = "WebBrowser",
   MenuHandler = new SearchContextMenuHandler(this),
   DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler(download_img),
   KeyboardHandler = new MyKeyboardHandler(this)
};
```

Comment: es exactamente al nivel en que estoy... pero no logro que mi código funcione dentro de la interface.

Comment: acabo de actualizar la pregunta

Comment: Si utilizas propiedades o métodos del form o de otros objectos, podrías pasarselos a la instancia MyKeyboardHandler para poder utilizarlos dentro de las implementaciones de la interface.  Así como publicaste tu código, no veo por qué no funcionaría.

Comment: como seria eso??

Comment: incluso no me deja usar VOID OnKeyEvent ...

Comment: estoy pensando en algo así: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35839019/4717133

Comment: o mejor aun, como deshabilito el bloque que cefsharp inpone cuando se despliega un control ... y que permita continuar utilizando los programado en el form1 XD

Comment: Haz publico el metodo y pasa una referencia del form. Ve el edit.